# Single application instance per network

Tags: c#, instance, mutex, synchronize

We have developed some long running C# console applications which will be run by Windows Scheduled tasks.

These applications might be run on many different server machines on intranet/extranet. 
We cannot ensure that they run on one machine because each application might need access to some resources, which are available only on a certain machine.

Still, all these applications are using a common WCF service to access the database.

We need to ensure, that there is only instance of one of our applications running at any moment.
As the apps might be on different extranet computers, we cannot use per-machine mutexes or MSMQ.

I have thought about the following solution - WCF Mutex service with a timeout. When one app runs, it checks to see if it is already launched (maybe on another machine) and then (in a dedicated thread) periodically pings the WCF Mutex service to update the timestamp (if ping fails, the app exits immediately). If the timestamp gets expired, this means, that the application has crashed, so it can be run again.

**I would like to know, if this "WCF mutex" is optimal solution for my problem. Maybe there are already some third party libraries which have implemented such functionality?**

Answer (score 1):

You mutex solution has a race condition.

If an app on a different server checks the timestamp in the window after the timestamp expired, but before the current service had updated the timestamp you will have two instances running.

I'd probably go the opposite route. I'd have a central monitoring service. This service would continually monitor the health of the system. If it detects a service went down, it would restart it on either that machine or a different one.

You may want to bite the bullet and go with a full Enterprise Service Bus. Check the Wikipedia article for ESBs. It lists over a dozen commercial and open source systems.

Comment: Thanks for a notice about that race condition. I guess, I could work it around if the expiration timeout is greater than keep-alive request period. It would be not an issue for my applications to wait 20-30 minutes more, after the running instance has quit.

Answer (score 0):

How about a file lock on a network location?

If you can create/open the file with exclusive read write then it is the only app running. If this running app then subsequently crashes, the lock is released automaticaly by the OS.

Tim

Oops, just re-read the question and saw "extranet", ignore me!