# Single java application instance per network

Tags: java, locking, distributed, single-instance

We have deployed a java application which will be run by a job scheduler.

This application might be run on many different server machines of intranet. Now we had a problem that there might be more than one instance of this application running simultaneously on multiple machine of product env, and that's a nightmare and we must to avoid that.

So I would like to know what's the proper way to ensure only one single application instance can be run per network.

Comment: There is a [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090442/single-application-instance-per-network) on SO asking the same question as I am. But its a C# one, and I do not found solution there. so I asked here. sorry for duplication.

Comment: That depends so much on your application, your environment and other things. There's no standard "SingleNetworkApplication" solution.

Comment: It's a standalone java application, and the environment is intranet, for example, production environment.

Comment: Well that was helpful. Like I said, there's no standard "SingleNetworkApplication" solution.

Comment: One approach is to have a scheduler rule where the next run of the app will not start until the previous run completes.  Another approach is to simplify and have the standalone code on a single active server (with possibly a cold standby).  So if you have a naive scheduler it can only execute on the single machine.  The shell script which starts the app can check to see if the process is already running.